# Bulk Upload to Box* using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, box-api

I'm facing some performance issues while uploading files to Box. There are about 50000 images I need to upload. I suspected that it could be because I'm uploading them one by one. Therefore, I thought of trying bulk upload to upload. Following is a snippet of my code:

```
List<String> filesToUpload = new ArrayList<String>();
public boolean processImage(File imageToProcess, String newName, String temp_location, String boxLocation) throws MagickException {
    File renamedImage = renameImage(newName, temp_location);
    boolean isProcessed = convertToPNG(imageToProcess, 
            renamedImage);
    String filePath = renamedImage.getPath();
    System.out.println("Processed Image: "+filePath);
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("processEntries - filePath " + filePath);
    }
    filesToUpload.add(filePath);
    if (filesToUpload.size() == 100) {
        UploadFileAsAppUser.uploadFilesAsBoxAppUser(filesToUpload, boxLocation);
        filesToUpload = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return isProcessed;
}
```

I haven't tested it. If the list size is 100 it will start uploading the images to Box but it will also stop generating the images on the same side.

I can create two threads. One will generate images and another will upload images. But in my upload images block, I'm also setting the list to empty that will happen once all 100 images have been uploaded. But if I wait for all 100 images to be uploaded and then start generating next set of images (because I'm clearing the list and initializing it to empty), then there is no use of having multiple threads.

Should I have two lists? Thread1 will generate the first 100 images. Once done, Thread2 will start will start uploading and at the same time the first thread will start generating another set of images to list 2 and so on..

Let me know if it's confusing. I can explain further. Thanks!

Comment: Uh...  Can I just answer "yes?" :)

Comment: Well. A small example would really help. :)

Comment: That's not really how SO works.  We can help you fix issues, but we "show me how to code X" isn't really what this is about.  I'll offer some advice though, rather than pass lists around and manage threads yourself, look into `ExecutorService`.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial  Your main thread can generate images and submit upload `Runnable` instances.  Then you can tune the upload by setting the number of threads in the pool.  Also, to upload, maybe gzipping could help too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try uploading the images in parallel. Transmission over the Internet works better when using multiple parallel connections.

I'm not familiar with the Box API, but a quick check reveals that it does use a thread pool for [large file uploads](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/box/sdk/LargeFileUpload.java#L53), so something like this should be possible:

```
final int numberOfParallelUploads = 5;
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfParallelUploads);
final BoxFolder boxFolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(boxApi);
for (/* each input file */) {
    final String fileName = /* get next file to upload */;
    pool.execute(() -> {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
            boxFolder.uploadFile(is, fileName);
        }
    });
}
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.HOURS); // absolute timeout for uploading all the files
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I also generate the images in parallel?

Comment: Reduced from 232 minutes to 22 minutes :)

Comment: Good to hear. Of course generating images in parallel is also a good idea.

Comment: Seems like I cannot generate images in parallel due to some limitations in our application server. Now I'm limited to upload in parallel. I don't have a list of images. It's like I was generating and then uploading on by one. How do I maintain a list while image generation is in progress?